# Fix dangling commits and tags in a git repository

Tags: git, repository, commit

I have a bare git repository that, according to `git fsck --full`, has about 300 dangling commits and tags. About 90% of it are dangling tags.

I'm not sure where these issues come from, but since the repository seems to work fine, they might have been there for a while already.

I would like to fix them, but so far nothing I tried made the issues go away. So far I have tried these commands:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git repack -a -d
```

How can I fix these dangling commits and tags? Are they a problem at all?
It is important that I don't lose the history and tags and I'm a bit concerned about the many dangling tags.

Best regards

Comment: [Git: what is a dangling commit/blob and where do they come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/git-what-is-a-dangling-commit-blob-and-where-do-they-come-from)

Comment: Okay, so it seems better to ignore it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Dangling commits and tags are commits and tags which are not "reachable" which means that they are not the part of the history of `HEAD` or any branch. **If and only if you currently do not miss any commit**, then you can remove them. To delete dangling commits, DrZoo has already posted a good link. Deleting tags using git can be a little bit tricky sometimes. But You can also remove tags manually. If git says you have a

```
dangling tag b61fdaf08acb1412b629b1913da21143775e523a
```

for example then you can remove this by removing the file

```
repositoryfolder\.git\objects\b6\1fdaf08acb1412b629b1913da21143775e523a
```

Comment: .git\objects does not seem to contain such objects after gc (git 2.25.1)


```├── lost-found
│   ├── commit
│   │   ├── 248eba3d3eb468f568e281a30c2baa38118a08d5
...
│   │   └── cb466b9f92d9164c7eb27acb6e6185066fe7cf3a
│   └── other
│       ├── 0025ed61b844057da4ed9b149ad3533bc067af5d
...
│       └── efa6dfa5b4d56670daad211c91c8ddb98e392330
├── objects
│   ├── info
│   │   ├── commit-graph
│   │   └── packs
│   └── pack
│       ├── pack-43fc3ebfb008ea685aa0a82c4bbe875f6857c3e8.idx
│       └── pack-43fc3ebfb008ea685aa0a82c4bbe875f6857c3e8.pack
├── ORIG_HEAD```